# Ajax Gantt Chart possibly jQuery based

Tags: looking-for-a-script, jquery, ajax

I'm looking for a free or commercial Ajax Gantt Chart that should possibly be jQuery based.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gantt Chart - JavaScript / JSP / Java / Groovy / Grails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100502/gantt-chart-javascript-jsp-java-groovy-grails)

Comment: That other question is about server side technology to get the chart. This questioner is looking for client side technology.

Answer (score 1):

How about jQuery.ganttView?
https://github.com/thegrubbsian/jquery.ganttView